# Search for a Regular Expression in Swift 3

Tags: regex, swift, swift3

At the moment I'm converting my project to Swift 3.

I have a code block like this:

```
let someString = "asd.asABCDEFG.HI"
let regexp = "^\\w*[.]\\w{2}"
let range = someString.rangeOfString(regexp, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
let result = someString.substringWithRange(range!)
```

The `rangeOfString` method is gone in Swift 3. Can somebody post an example, how a regexp search can be done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Swift 3 `rangeOfString` is like `range(of:options:)` and `substringWithRange` is like `substring(with:)`.

```
if let range = someString.range(of:regexp, options: .regularExpression) {
    let result = someString.substring(with:range)
}
```