# Search multiple words in one string in swift

Tags: swift, string

I have a long string in swift3 and want to check if it contains word1 **and** word2. It could also be more than 2 search words. I found out following solution:

```
var Text = "Hello Swift-world"
var TextArray = ["Hello", "world"]
var count = 0

for n in 0..<TextArray.count {
    if (Text.contains(TextArray[n])) {
        count += 1
    }
}

if (count == TextArray.count) {
    print ("success")
}
```

But this seems very complicated, is there not an easier way to solve this? (Xcode8 and swift3)

Comment: Note that variable names should be `lowerCamelCase`, you don't need to use parenthesis around if conditions and to iterate over an array you can just say `for element in array {...}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking for *less code:*

```
let text = "Hello Swift-world"
let wordList = ["Hello", "world"]

let success = !wordList.contains(where: { !text.contains($0) })
print(success)
```

It is also a little more efficient than your solution because
the `contains` method returns as soon as a "not contained" word
is found.

As of **Swift 4** or later, you can use [`allSatisfy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy):

```
let success = wordList.allSatisfy(text.contains)
```

Comment: why using ! exclamation mark ? I don't understand how it works

Comment: @MehdiS.: The goal is to print "true" if the text contains all of the words in the list, i.e. if `wordList` does *not* contain a word which does *not* occur in the text. – However, this can be expressed more nicely in modern Swift, see the update.

Comment: crystal clear thank you for your update

Answer (score 3):

A more Swifty solution that will stop searching after it found a non-existent word:

```
var text = "Hello Swift-world"
var textArray = ["Hello", "world"]

let match = textArray.reduce(true) { !$0 ? false : (text.range(of: $1) != nil ) }
```

Another way to do it which stops after it found a non-match:

```
let match = textArray.first(where: { !text.contains($0) }) == nil
```

Comment: Note that this won't stop iterating after finding a non-match.

Comment: It won't stop iterating, but those iterations will be fast as they won't invoke `text.range(of: )`

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility [is regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676876/search-for-a-regular-expression-in-swift-3):

```
// *'s are wildcards
let regexp = "(?=.*Hello*)(?=.*world*)"

if let range = Text.range(of:regexp, options: .regularExpression) {
    print("this string contains Hello world")
} else {
    print("this string doesn't have the words we want")
}
```

Comment: If you go that route with a dynamic word list (perhaps from user input) then you can use `NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for:)` to avoid problems with special characters.